# Visual Studio: Find and replace with Regular expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I want to substitute lot's of different lines in a decompiled project:

```
get_Method();
set_Method(value);
```

This is how the code i'm working on refers to methods with get and set attributes
So I should change all of this call to

```
Method;
Method = value;
```

But it's impossible to change manually every line of this kind...
I think it's likely to change them all at once using the regular expressions, but I really don't know how to do it, I tried a lot and i'm just messing things up

Can someone give me an example of regular expression that can help me change every `.get_Method()`  into `.Method`
and every `set_Method(` into `.Method = (`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Replacing `\.get_(.*?)\(\)` with `$1` and replacing `\.set_(.*?)\((.*?)\)` with `$1 = $2` is what you need.

[Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Comment: with a dot right before the group reference it seems to work! I never properly understood regex, and it's a huge downside since is really usefull, this expressions anyway seems to work properly! Thanks!

Comment: there was a few information about inputs and outputs in your question. It's good that worked, and It's better trying to use and become familiar with Regex. @FenriX